# Is this seven or eight consecutive roads in catan?

Tags: catan

If someone has roads all the way around a hex in catan (six roads), and one road on each opposite end of that hex, is that a total of seven towards the longest road or eight.  In other words do both roads on either end count or only one since it goes around in a circle?

Comment: In particular this answer covers it: http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/15538/122